# Handle Cancel click on Windows authentication

Tags: identityserver4

I need to run IdentityServer4 with both Windows Authentication and Basic Authentication.
For now, when I trying to login to IdentityServer4 on PC that is not connected to ActiveDirectory, browser shows Login form, where I can fill ActiveDirectory credentials.
This is OK.

But now I need to handle click Cancel button on this form, and redirect to local login only HTML form, where I can login with credentials form database (I using .NET Core Authentication).
Now when I click Cancel, I'm redirected to 401 error site. Is it possible to handle?

[image: Form where I click "Cancel"]

Comment: Can you show the code for this action?

Comment: I using code from [IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/release/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L158) - lines 158-197.

Answer (score 2):

I fell in the same situation and in my case I use this middleware extension method

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
{
    if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

        await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(
            string.Format("<script>window.location='../account/Login{0}'</script> ", context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString));
    }
});
```