# How to handle cancel button of windows authentication pop-up in asp.net core mvc deployed on Kestrel?

Tags: authentication, .net-core, error-handling, asp.net-core-mvc, windows-authentication

I'm trying to implement mixed authentication windows + cookie based in asp.net core mvc application. When windows authentication is canceled I want to redirect user to fallback page where can choose windows or cookie based authentication. The app will be deployed on Kestrel not IIS. I'm using .net core 3.1.

Basically I need to redirect user on fallback page when http status code is 401 and substatus code is 1 or 2.

So far I tried to use status code pages as fallows:

In Startup.cs I added

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/Status", "?statusCode={0}");
```

In ErrorController.cs

```
public IActionResult Status(int statusCode)
        {
            var statusCodeReExecuteFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();

            if (statusCode == 401)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Fallback");
            }

            var originalURL =
                statusCodeReExecuteFeature.OriginalPathBase
                + statusCodeReExecuteFeature.OriginalPath
                + statusCodeReExecuteFeature.OriginalQueryString;

            return Redirect(originalURL);
        }
```

This not works because it breaks windows authentication handshake.

I also tried to implement custom error handler and check HttpResponse.StatusCode == 401, but the error controller method is not hit probably because windows authentication is handled by another layer ..

Comment: Duplicate of Handle Cancel click on Windows authentication(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792133/handle-cancel-click-on-windows-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

It took me a few days before I almost thought it can't be done. But finally I figured it out.
My problem was when executing External Authentication on Identity Server 4. I couldn't catch the event when the user clicks "Cancel". I got 401 status code for entering Windows Authentication, for clicking "Cancel" and also when clicking "Signin". The solution is the following:
Place this line in Startup.cs in public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app):

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/external/ErrorPage", "?statusCode={0}");
```

After that just create a IActionResult function in controller like this:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ErrorPage(int? statusCode = null)
        {
            if (statusCode.HasValue)
            {
                    return View(new SomeViewModel() { ErrorMessage = statusCode.Value.ToString()});
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Hi,
thanks for that but I also don't understand why it is working. Anyways, I added following part to your Error funtion:
var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();
            if (statusCode.HasValue && "/Account/WinLogin" == feature.OriginalPath)
            {
                     return View("../Account/LoginError", new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
            }