# Handling Windows Authentication failure in Blazor Server app (Kestrel)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, blazor, kestrel-http-server

I am making a Blazor intranet app with Windows Authentication for domain users, using Kestrel, and .NET 6.0.11. Following the instructions in [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core (31 Aug 2022)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0#kestrel), i.e. adding to `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => { options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy; });
// ...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

This does work, but:

- Authentication is performed as soon as the user first connects, and

  - If authentication fails , the user gets a HTTP 401 response.
- There does not appear to be any way to allow anonymous access.

I have found that `app.UseStatusCodePages(Text.Plain, "Status Code Page: {0}");` works to "improve" the 401 response, however (unsurprisingly) `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/SomePage/{0}");` still generates the 401 response, presumably because `SomePage` has the same issue.

The presence of `app.UseAuthorization()` in `Program.cs` seems to force the authentication to happen on user's first connection. I have tried commenting it out, which (surprisingly) causes the app to run successfully with no authentication even attempted; the `GetClaimsPrincipal` demo reports no user is authenticated.

(Side question - why is this; I would expect it to try authenticating but then report user as authenticated or not; but with no authorization).

**My question is:** Is it possible at all to do either of the following things:

1. Not challenge for authentication at first, but do it only when the user navigates to a certain page or presses a button; or
2. If the startup Windows Authentication failed, allow Blazor page execution to proceed with no authorized user? (I would use the `AuthorizedView`, and authorization attributes to limit access to what is appropriate for unauthorized users, and advise them to reload the page to try again).

---

*Note:* The question [How to handle cancel button of windows authentication pop-up in asp.net core mvc deployed on Kestrel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60035884/how-to-handle-cancel-button-of-windows-authentication-pop-up-in-asp-net-core-mvc) is similar but for an old version of ASP.NET Core 3: it answers my part (2) with the "trick" being to directing the HTTP error handler to a `new View()` presumably running "outside" of the rest of the project structure and therefore not triggering automatic authentication again.

However the code in that question does not work in Blazor: it uses `HttpContext` directly (deprecated now); and it has a different project structure so I don't even see where the code would go.

Comment: Yes, all that is by default, you have to specify how you want the authorization to happen etc. To my knowledge just enabling authorization middleware should not reject any requests. Those routes have to be specifically marked as requiring authorization. I think it’s the fallback policy being set which makes this not allow anything. Try removing it.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Changing to `builder.Services.AddAuthorization()` (i.e. without adding the fallback policy) causes the app to run with no authentication performed. Is there something I can then call to manually trigger authentication to happen?